# How to pass two parameters when using std::mem_fun?

Tags: c++, stl

Lets say I have hierarchy like this (This is just a test program. Please do not point anything related to memory leaks, destructor is not virtual etc):

```
class I
{
public:
    virtual void fun(int n, int n1) = 0;
};

class A : public I
{
public:
    void fun(int n, int n1)
    {
        std::cout<<"A::fun():" <<n<<" and n1:" <<n1<<"\n";
    }
};

class B : public I
{
public:
    void fun(int n, int n1)
    {
        std::cout<<"B::fun():" <<n<<" and n1:" <<n1<<"\n";
    }
};


int  main()
{
    std::vector<I*> a;
    a.push_back(new A);
    a.push_back(new B);

    //I want to use std::for_each to call function fun with two arguments.
}
```

How do I call fun() method which takes two arguments using the std::for_each ? I think I have to use std::mem_fun probably with std::bind2nd but am not able to figure out how to do this. Any clue how to achieve this? I am not using boost.

Comment: Does not using boost mean you don't have tr1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create your own functor like this:

```
class Apply
{
private:
  int arg1, arg2;

public:
  Apply(int n, int n1)
    : arg1(n), arg2(n1) 
  {}        

  void operator() (I* pI) const
  {
    pI->fun(arg1, arg2);
  }
};

int main ()
{
  // ...
  std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), Apply(n, n1));
}
```

or use boost::bind like this:

```
std::for_each(
  a.begin(),
  a.end(),
  boost::bind(&I::fun, _1, n, n1));
```

Comment: I was hoping that I can avoid writing a functor..looks like there is no way out. Isn't it?

Comment: I don't know if there is a way using only stl since a std::mem_fun accepts at most one argument.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this with the std binders.  You can of course write your own functor.

```
struct TwoArguments
{
   int one;
   int two;

   TwoArguments( int one, int two ) : one(one),two(two){
   }

   void operator()( I* i ) const {
       i->fun( one, two );
   }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be to use templates. (Please tell me if it's a bad practice though!)

```
template<int N, int N1>
void Apply(I* i)
{
  i->fun(N, N1);
}

std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), Apply<firstParam, secondParam>);
```

That would be good if you don't intend to call it with a lot of different parameters since it would generate code for every combination you made.

Comment: thats interesting.. I never thought about implementing it like this.

Comment: But this solution only works if the parameters N, N1 are known at compile time. You cannot write

std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), Apply<getN(), getN1()>);